# How get reach of Grub at Debian and going to desktop environment?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, grub

Recently I installed Debian Distro of Linux as a 2nd operating system,
When I chose the Debian operating system during boot, a command prompt (like to Terminal at Ubuntu) starts with message "Welcome to Grub" and I don't know how go to inside the Linux desktop environment.

Comment: It seems that you have somehow managed to install the GRUB boot code without the configuration file. Re-installing GRUB from the install disc should resolve it. I use Ubuntu, so I can't be sure of the best solution for native Debian, but search for `update grub from debian install disk` and choose an answer that looks straight-forward. You may well rewrite the boot code that's already there, but that won't matter. Just make sure you are installing to the correct place before committing any changes to disc.

Comment: I downloaded iso file of debian OS from [link](https://www.debian.org/) and installed with bootable USB flash.

Answer (score -1):

In Ubuntu the "startx" command will start the gui desktop environment, but I'm not sure about debian. I'm still a Linux noob so I probably won't be of much help to you.